# Ember.js for non-Ruby users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ember.js

EmberJS is great framework and very familiar to me with it's concept.
However all examples and starter kits are for Ruby (Rake, etc).

Did anybody work with Ember and .NET MVC in example?

**UPDATE**:

Here is how I found to have router w
part with AMD. It is very complicated even for simple example:

```
define(['ember'], function (Ember) {
return Ember.Router.extend({
    root:Ember.Route.extend({
        index:Ember.Route.extend({
            route:'/'
        }),
        contributors:Ember.Route.extend({
            route:'/contributors',
            connectOutlets:function (router) {
                var controller = router.get('applicationController');
                require(['app/controllers/contributors', 'app/views/contributors'],
                    function (contributorsController, contributorsView) {
                        controller.connectOutlet({
                            viewClass:contributorsView,
                            controller:contributorsController.create()
                        });
                    });
            }
        })
    })
});
```

});

I am now rethinking if AMD is good solution for Ember. Tom Dale mentioned [alternative](http://tomdale.net/2012/01/amd-is-not-the-answer/) but didn't provide example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made this example, but it's still missing a lot of things

https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/hello-ember-router

Just note that I did this while I was trying to learn but haven't touched in a while.

Comment: Nice example. I saw the code. Don't you think that Route part in ember application can become very very big. Is there any option to split routing into smaller chunks or make it dynamic?

i.e. ":controller/:action" ?

Comment: Yes, the routes get pretty big. As for the next version of this I'm moving to ember1.0pre and adding ember-data, as well as separating all scripts into different files and fetching them when needed. Like I said, I was learning it and never really got time to touch it again since I've published.

Comment: Looking forward to see more work. How do you fetching files when needed? AMD or..?

Comment: More than likely AMD. I'm working on a different project now that is taking too much of my time, but I'd love to implement these changes soon... I will be happy if I can do this before the first snow :)

Comment: Btw, you should probably check my Ember related questions on my profile. There are some differences in the way the json format JSON.NET generates and the json format Ember-Data expects.

Comment: FYI, the router API is currently getting once over in master to slim it down.

Comment: @LukeMelia It's looking good. When is the final coming out? sometime this next spring?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Hopefully well before that.